# Change the tooltip text when selecting item in listview

Tags: vb.net

I have a listview containing the source addresses of files (from user system) and the destination addresses (two columns, multilpe selection = false).

Since the source addresses might be quite long like:

> d:\root\branch1\branch2\branch3\branch4\myfile.dat

the first column shows just:

> d:\ ... \myfile.dat

The real path is stored in the ListViewItem.Tag

I want to have a tooltip showing the whole path every time the user clicks (or changes) the selected item. I came out with this:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        For Each locItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
            With ToolTip1
                .RemoveAll()
                .SetToolTip(ListView1, locItem.Tag)
            End With
        Next
    End Sub
```

Now, the tooltip does change, but it always skip one selection. That is:

- selecting item 1: tooltip shows correctly
- selecting item 2: tooltip don't show
- selecting item 3: tooltip shows correctly
- selecting item 5: tooltip don't show
- selecting item 2: tooltip shows correctly (selection went back to item 2 which didn't show the 1st time)

Any idea?

PS: I am using Visual Studio Community 2015

PPS: I also need to have the View property set to View.Details (to show both columns and headers), so setting `ShowItemToolTip = True` does not work

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

I found a workaround, destroying and recreating the tooltip control. Now the tooltip shows correctly on every item:

```
  Private myTooltip As ToolTip
    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If myTooltip IsNot Nothing Then myTooltip.Dispose()
        myTooltip = New ToolTip
        For Each locItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
            myTooltip.SetToolTip(ListView1, locItem.Tag)
        Next
    End Sub
```

I'm still baffled about the skipping in the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

ListView has a property called ShowItemToolTips (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.showitemtooltips(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can set that to true and then set the ToolTipText property of the ListViewItems to the long path.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ListView1.ShowItemToolTips = True

    Dim lvi1 As New ListViewItem With {.Text = "d:\..\myFile.dat", .Tag = "d:\myLongPath\myFile.dat", .ToolTipText = .Tag}
    Dim lvi2 As New ListViewItem With {.Text = "d:\..\myFile2.dat", .Tag = "d:\myLongPath\myFile2.dat", .ToolTipText = .Tag}

    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi1)
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to have **View.Details** as View setting.
what you suggest works only in **View.List** mode.
My bad I wasn't more specific